# Render text as HTML in visualforce page or custom field?

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, html

I would like option for users to post text as html to a custom object page layout. (custom field doesn't seem possible as it looks like Rich Text field doesn't render HTML)

Moving from JIRA to Salesforce and in JIRA could copy and paste code to an issue and format it to look more readable. Would like to be able to do this in Salesforce with a custom object we use to track issues. (probably using  tags or something similar).